# Value of Fourier series at boundaries

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Assume we have a function f(x) which can be represented through Fourier series F(x) in (-L,L).Is it general property that [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50XXQ.png)

If it is, how can this be proved?

Comment: Try first with $f(x) = (x+1/2) - \lfloor x+1/2 \rfloor, L = 1/2$

Comment: Is the second absolute value of x+1/2?

Comment: @QurbanOrucov, is the floor function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla, got it thanks!